npx serve Network address not accessible from phone
So I call npx serve in my computer's directory to expose html pages to the network. According to the docs, this thing starts on two http addresses: Local localhost:3000 and Network [my_ip]:3000. I was reasonably expecting that entering [my_ip]:3000 into the phone (on the same network the computer is) would allow me to access the html pages. But the connection times out.
I've tried searching for a solution. I am pretty sure the firewall is not the issue. This thing already listens to 0.0.0.0:3000. Using Chrome USB debug tools is a workaround that works, but I want to sort this Network stuff out. Using Windows. I am sure I am missing some crucial detail. The help would be much appreciated.
